# Geodatabase archival storage

Tags: esri-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, storage, archiving

We are trying to enable Geodatabase (Oracle 18c) archiving (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/manage-data/geodatabases/geodatabase-archiving.htm)

Our architecture team recommends we separate out the tablespaces for primary tables and archival tables and use 'SAN (Block) - XIV' for primary and 'NAS (File)- NetApp' storage for the archive tables.

Now, since the data gets archived as users edit, will this have any performance impacts?

Also, archive data is what users will be utilizing to do 'time-lapse' animations and such using UI tools.

Will this storage impact the performance of such tools?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a misunderstanding. With archiving in ArcGIS there are no separate tables that hold the history or anything. History is determined by a FromDate and a ToDate field that are set automatically by ArcGIS when editing. What you see in e.g. ArcMap is a database view that selects records where 'now' is between those two dates.

If you ever disable archiving, you'll have the option to store the history in a separate table (with a *_H* suffix)

Maybe your architecture team was thinking of [Versioning](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/an-overview-of-versioning.htm), which *does* have separate tables.